# Can I use prebuilt shared libs(.so) for arm abi in my apk, with no NDK?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have a bunch of prebuilt libraries, which satisfies all my apps requirements. But, I don't want to compile anything, just use functions from that shared libs. Should I just add .so files to /app/src/main/jniLibs and .... use JNI functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call native methods from Java, only from a native library.
What JNI does is allow you to bridge the two worlds by marking Java methods with the `native` keyword, such that calling these methods jumps into a corresponding function in a native library.

The "JNI functions" are only available in the native side and they are meant for inspecting and manipulating Java objects. For example there is a `CallVoidMethod` for calling Java methods that return `void`.

Comment: So, If I have my c functions (which are provided by that .so libs) declared with native keyword in some class, can I use them in code?

Comment: Probably not directly: the calling convention must match (the JVM passes a `JNIEnv*` and either a `jclass` or a `jobject` as first two arguments), and you must either name your functions specially (something akin to `Java_pkg_class_method`) or use `RegisterNatives` to link Java `native` methods to function pointers.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, this requirements is met for now. But, old .so libraries ain't gonna work: "dlopen failed: has text relocations"